# Can I use LyX as a compiler?

Tags: lyx, compiling

Is there a setting on LyX where I can write directly in LaTeX and use it as a compiler?

Comment: lyx uses a tex system in the background, it does not itself process the tex code, so there is not really any advantage to doing this you could write the latex in any editor and pass it straight to tex.

Answer (score 2):

Partly.

You cannot write the whole preamble yourself, but you could add a TeX code box with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> and write the entire document, i.e. everything between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`, directly as LaTeX code.

(I cannot honestly see why you would do that though, it's better to write LaTeX code in an actual LaTeX editor.)